# How to place minitoc in right place where some chapters are with star?

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, starred-version, minitoc

I have a `main.tex` file. There is a part called front matter. Part of the code is,

1.

```
\frontmatter
\selectlanguage{english}
\include{title}
\include{dedication}
\include{acknowledgements}
\include{abstract}
```

And I have files called `title.txt` ... `abstract.txt`

2.
The acknowledgement file looks like,

```
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements} 
My text here..
```

3.
The abstract file looks like

```
\chapter*{abstract}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract} 
My text here..
```

Main body, or main matter looks like,

```
\mainmatter
\include{ch1} 
\include{ch2}
\include{ch3}
```

ch1, ch2 and ch3 has minitoc.

```
\chapter{This is title of chapter 1}
\minitoc
```

Now, for example, after I have added this `\include{abstract}` and `\include{ack...}` in the `main.tex` 
The minitoc disappeared from chapter 1 and chapter 2. But in chapter 3, first minitoc appeared but, this minitoc was about chapter 1.

May be this is something to do with the chapter command with the start.

```
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
```

But how can I fix it?
[How can I have minitoc of chapter 1, in right place?]

Comment: I have found a solution,

In the abstract file change the 

\chapter*{abstract}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract} 

to

\chapter*{abstract}\addstarredchapter{Abstract}

It worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why `minitoc` acts this way, but a simple solution (or at least workaround) is to replace the `\chapter*`/`\addcontentsline` combos by `\chapter` (the unstarred version). The "Acknowledgements"  and "Abstract"  chapters still won't be numbered as they are a part of `\frontmatter`. As an additional benefit, this solution will produce correct headings for the two chapters.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{minitoc}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\dominitoc
\tableofcontents

% \chapter*{Acknowledgements}
% \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements} 
\chapter{Acknowledgements}

% \chapter*{Abstract}
% \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract} 
\chapter{Abstract}

\mainmatter

\chapter{First}
\minitoc

\section{First-First}

\section{First-Second}

\chapter{Second}
\minitoc

\section{Second-First}

\section{Second-Second}

\chapter{Third}
\minitoc

\section{Third-First}

\section{Third-Second}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help. Thanks for explaining so neatly. I have found another solution that I have added as a comment to my question.
Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and after trying out a few methods, the simplest answer to this, in my opinion, is to just add

```
\setcounter{mtc}{x}
```

immediately before the first use of a minitoc.

'x' is the number of chapters before the first chapter where a minitoc is required.

This just tells the minotoc which chapter it should be displaying.