# strange behavior of secttoc

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

I use package `minitoc` in article class (`\secttoc`) but its behavior is strange for me. I have 3 sections, it creates `.maf`, `.mtc`, `.mtc0`, `.stc1`, `.stc2` and `.stc3` files. Contents of `.stc1`, `.stc2` and `.stc3` are correct but in document, `secttoc` for first section is OK, for second section it print content of section 3 and in section3 it write

> Warning: W0049: You hace attempted to insert empty secttoc". Looks like it correctly write .stX files but read incorrectly...

I have one `.tex` file with preamble and several other `.tex` file I `\include` in main `.tex`. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Without [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) hard to say, but perhaps: »[How to place minitoc in right place where some chapters are with star?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51641)« or »[Minitoc of wrong chapter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291743)« or »[Minitoc and unnumbered chapters](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236217)« or »[Why the index of a certain chapter is put on 2 chapters later?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159674)«

Comment: Ok, thank, but no one is my case. MWE...no idea, I tried to prepare one, but all of my tests  are ok...except of my .tex included other .tex files. BUt that means 70 pages of text...Give it up, I spent 3 days with this, I´m exhausted. I will make mini tables of cnts. manually.

Comment: Past, I haven´t given it up, I have found \setcounter{stc}{x}, that solved my problem. Thx  Schweinebacke for direct me.

Comment: IMHO `\adjuststc` or `\incrementstc` or `\decrementstc` would be better.

Comment: @Schweinebacke: Providing some answer? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I could if there would be a MWE in the question.

Comment: @Schweinebacke: Yes, fair point.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue could be solved in comments